# i want to get facebook userid which i can pass on to my website to keep track of user

Tags: facebook, userid

i want to get facebook userid which i can pass on to my website to keep track of user when i click a link on my app. The purpose is to provide 10% discount to all new user who go from facebook to our website but only for one time

Answer (score 1):

Get the GraphAPI, which should get you the ID. Also, depending on your programming environment, there may be more convenient modules for the purpose - check out.

Kudos, for your good intentions of offering a discount! All the Best in Business.